# Markov Decision Process representation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, markov-process

I'm attempting to model a simple process using a Markov Decision Process.

Let $A$ be a set of $3$ actions : $ A \in \{b,s\}$. 
$T(s,a,s')$ represents the probability of if in state $s$ , take action $a$ and end up in state $s'$

Notation for the MDP diagram is as follows :

[image]

Here is my MDP diagram which models 7 states:

The outgoing actions for each state sum to 1.

[image]

$T(1,b,2) = .7 $

$T(1,b,3) = .3 $

$T(1,s,4) = .9 $

$T(1,s,5) = .05 $

$T(1,s,6) = .05 $

I've tried to keep this as simple as possible to check my understanding. Are my representations & probabilities correct ?

Comment: What is action 'h`? That is not being modeled.

Comment: @BrianSpiering I've not included 'h' , it can be modeled but I've not included it. I've removed 'h' for clarity, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks 'correct' to me, in the sense that it satisfies the requirements for being an MDP. Whether it models the underlying real-world problem correctly cannot be validated with the information given here.